# Css moving the divs in left and right

Tags: html, css

I have the "left ads" div and a "right ads" div and the main content and menu at the center. I want to move the "left ads" div in left so that so that the "menu bar" and all the content below it gets at top. And i want to move the "right ads" div in right . Also after moving them they should be independent i.e what ever be their content they should not effect the middle div i.e main content div .[Please view it in desktop in full screen]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#adleft{
    background: pink;
}

#wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#topmenubar{
    background:violet;
}

#logoandad{
    background:greenyellow;
}

#main_content{
    background: azure;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#featuredcontent{
    background: burlywood;
}

#morecontents{
    background: crimson;
}

#allquizes{
    background: chocolate;
}

#adright{
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/quiz.css">
    <title>QuizOm</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="adscontainers" id="adleft">Left Ads</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="topmenubar">Menu Bar</div>
<div id="logoandad">Logo and Ads</div>
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="featuredcontent">
        <div class="twoupperbox">Featured content 1</div>
        <div class="twoupperbox">Featured content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="morecontents">
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten1</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten2</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="allquizes">
        <h1>All Quizes</h1>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz1</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz2</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="adscontainers" id="adright">Right Ads</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried that ins't working?

Comment: used position absolute for left ads but didn't work and can't do anything about right ads .

Comment: Probably your best bet is to [use flex](https://codepen.io/torbencolding/pen/WboQPr) to achieve your layout, but honestly your current markup isn't conducive to working well.... further, at least some sort of mockup of your desired end result would be helpful.  You're asking us to do too much - and guaranteed, if someone answers, it won't be what you meant / wanted for some reason....

Comment: i just want is left ads be in left and right ads be in right . And thier height may be as high but it should not disturb the middle content(on desktop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be using `display:flex`

```css
#adleft{
    background: pink;
}

#wrapper{
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}

#topmenubar{
    background:violet;
}

#logoandad{
    background:greenyellow;
}

#main_content{
    background: azure;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#featuredcontent{
    background: burlywood;
}

#morecontents{
    background: crimson;
}

#allquizes{
    background: chocolate;
}

#adright{
    background: aqua;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/quiz.css">
    <title>QuizOm</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">


<div class="adscontainers" id="adleft">Left Ads</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="topmenubar">Menu Bar</div>
<div id="logoandad">Logo and Ads</div>
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="featuredcontent">
        <div class="twoupperbox">Featured content 1</div>
        <div class="twoupperbox">Featured content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="morecontents">
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten1</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten2</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">conten3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="allquizes">
        <h1>All Quizes</h1>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz1</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz2</div>
        <div class="bottomthreebox">All quiz3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="adscontainers" id="adright">Right Ads</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but is it not possible by general method ?